# Initiate Multiple Google Maps Instances

Tags: templating

I am trying to initiate multiple Google Map instances on a page.

I need to set a dynamic ID for each one. I've tried doing it with `loop.index` but no joy.

```
{% for marker in event.eventMap.getMarkers() %}
    <div class="google-maps">
        {% set options = {
            id: 'map',
            width: '100%',
            height: '150px',
            options: {
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 5,
                scrollwheel: false
            }
        } %}

        {{ craft.googleMaps.map() }}

        {{ craft.googleMaps.data('map', event.eventMap) }}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's happening?

Comment: I can't get the loop index to work. ie concatenate the 'map' and the loop index

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
{% for marker in event.eventMap.getMarkers() %}
    {% set mapId = 'map' ~ loop.index %}
    <div class="google-maps">
        {% set options = {
            id: mapId,
            width: '100%',
            height: '150px',
            options: {
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 5,
                scrollwheel: false
            }
        } %}

        {{ craft.googleMaps.map() }}

        {{ craft.googleMaps.data(mapId, event.eventMap) }}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```